# Oracle Date comparison

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date & time column. If I need data only for 1 day, which operator is faster, `=` or `between`.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to:

```
where col >= date '2020-01-01' and col < date '2020-01-02'
```

versus:

```
where trunc(col) = date '2020-01-01'
```

Then the first method is usually considered better.  The `trunc()` function impedes the optimizer (because statistics are not as good) and Oracle cannot use an index on just `col`.

That said, Oracle does support function-based indexes, so if you have an index on `trunc(col)`, then the second could use that index.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle `DATE` type always includes information for the date and time.

If you are **absolutely sure** you always saved data with the time as `00:00:00`, you can use a seek (equality). This is faster.

However, I would play it safe and use a range search (`BETWEEN`). This is a little bit slower, but still quite fast. Avoid using `TRUNC(date)` or any other expression manipulation, since it defeats index usage.